# API提供サーバーへのトラフィック軽減のため WebSocket を中継することは可能ですか？

Tags: api, websocket

お世話になります。

公開されているwebsocketAPIを一旦他のサーバー（自分の管理下）を通してwebサイト（自分の管理下）で表示させることは可能でしょうか。
※使用の合意はとれていて、経路でデータの加工はないとします

例えばある地点の気温を配信しているwebsocketAPIがあり、自分のwebサイトからトラフィックをあまり流したくないため一旦他のサーバーを中継し、webサイトのユーザーはそこからデータを取得するイメージです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご回答誠にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

可能です。
API サーバーに対しては WebSocket クライアントとして接続し、自サイトのユーザーに対しては WebSocket サーバーとしてふるまうプログラムを書くことになります。